# loading image by Loader.loadBytes(byteArray)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader

i like to ask about one thing :

If i create Loader and load external image by URLRequest , ill have result :

```
loader.content is Bitmap
loader.content.bitmapData is BitmapData
```

But if I use Loader.loadBytes(ImageBytes) , result is different even if ImageBytes is loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes :

```
bytesLoader.content is MovieClip
bytesLoader.content.getChildAt(0) is Bitmap
bytesLoader.content.getChildAt(0).bitmapData is BitmapData
```

why ?

Answer (score 0):

AS3 Loader has internal parsing to try and match datatypes to internal class types. It's pretty handy in most cases, but the syntax is a little weird.

In your example above, you CAN cast the bytesLoader.content as Bitmap if you'd rather.

Edit (in reference to the "how" question):

```
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getImage);

ldr.load ( new URLRequest ( IMAGE_URL ) );

function getImage (e:Event):void {
    var bmp:Bitmap = ldr.content as Bitmap;
    addChild (bmp);
}
```

You should be able to simply cast it as a Bitmap.

Comment: How ? If loader after load complete set content on its own and for loader.loadBytes content is MovieClip with Bitmap , not Bitmap

Comment: Im not talking about loader.load , but loader.loadBytes method and its result

Comment: I just did a test using loadBytes. I can still cast to Bitmap as well. I'm utilizing this method as part of an old blog post (http://labs.tomasino.org/2010/04/20/as3-duplicate-loaded-swf/). Seems to work just fine. Perhaps there's an issue with the data you're loading into the byte-array?

Comment: I load img by Loader.load and save its loaderContent.bytes to my project file , than reload project file and loadBytes